# Foreach String[] with timer in Android

Tags: java, android, loops, android-intent, timer

I'm implementing a timer inside of a foreach/for loop in android. There is a `TextField` or `TextView` (I'm agnostic as to which to use) that is populated every 30ms with the next string from a string array:

```
String[] faces = retrieve_pattern().split("\"");
```

I need help implementing this.

EDIT:
Boris, your example works, but it prints out all the strings, but I need to show just one string, and in "some time" delete it and show the following one until I reach the end. Sort of a text animation in TextField.

I've tried TimerTask, but couldn't make it work though.

Comment: So you want to implement a routine that adds an element to the TextView every 30ms until all elements are added?

Comment: That's not how you would do it. Use a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) or a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: Use a Timer in cunjunction with a TimerTask. Use the schedule method with 0ms as the delay and 30ms as the repeat. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Is that every 30 minutes on the clock, or every 30 consecutive minutes of having the app open?

Comment: Timer and TimerTask are a bad habit that persists from Java. Using getHandler().post(Runnable) is better when programming for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most appropriate way to do this is using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   private String [] mSplits;
   private int mSplitIndex;
   private Handler updater = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      TextView textView = (TextView)MyActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
      String text = mSplits[mSplitIndex++];
      textView.setText(text);
      if (mSplitIndex < mSplits.length) {
        sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 30);
      }
    }
   };
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_split);
    updater.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 0));
   }
}
```

I am writing by heart so if you encounter any problems write back.

Comment: Thanks Boris, I tried to follow your advise and now getting the following error, please see added edit for error.

Comment: @Jake: do you really do `setText` on your `TextView`? If so the new sting should replace the old one.